# I am not able to use variable tag in template Based email in marketing cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, email-template, journeybuilder

In journey builder ,I am creating a journey to send emails to the list of records in a data extension. I have selected the Email Then clicked Preview and test. By clicking the code view , I have options to add variable tags.But I am not able to use the variable tag. Kindly help me . Thanks in advance.

Note: I am beginner in marketing cloud

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use two sets of double percent symbols for the data that matches the field name in your data extension, i.e. `%%fullname%%`

Please see [Personalization Strings and AMPscript](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/personalizationStringsAMPscript.htm) for reference and also [Personalization Strings in Email Studio](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_available_personalization_strings.htm&type=5)